# Is there any reason for public methods in a package protected class?

Tags: java, class-visibility

I wonder if it makes any difference if a method is public or package protected in a class that is package protected.

```
class Example {
  public void test() {}
}
```

instead of

```
class Example {
  void test() {}
}
```

I guess the maximum visibility is given by the class. And a method can only reduce the visibility and increasing the visibility has no effect.

But it's valid syntax, so perhaps I've overseen something?

Comment: Thats a good question, i know in c++ theres a combination of protected+public that makes no effect in inheritance, my guess is that here it has effect for classes in the same package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we subclass `Example` to a `public` class , then code outside the package can access `test()` method using the subclass instance if it is `public` .

Example:

```
package A;
class Example {
   public void test() {}
}

package A;
public class SubExample extends Example {
}

package B;
import A.SubExample;
class OutsidePackage {
  public void some method(SubExample e){
    // Had test been defined with default access in class Example
    // the below line would be a compilation error.
    e.test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I can't follow you.

Comment: I tried to build an example using reflection. But I get the exception 'java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class other.Other can not access a member of class example.Example with modifiers "public"'. So it seems that the package protection of the class protects its public methods, too.

Comment: Good example, thank you. So it really makes a difference if the member is package protected or public!

Answer (score 7):

If `Example` implemented an interface of some kind you'd have to make them public, because you can't reduce access in that case.  All interface methods are, by default, public.

Comment: Good point. So would you always make your "package protected" methods public when the class is already package protected?

Comment: Not all.  I wouldn't make constructors public, because that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

As written, it does nothing. If it's a subclass or interface implementation, then it may be implementing or overriding methods that are declared public elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, it makes a difference. See the answer of @noob-unchained.